# How to clone element and then fadeOut and remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to leave a trail to my cursor with an image and I would like to make it fade before removing it.

I'm currently doing this :

```
$('#cursor').clone().appendTo(".trails").delay(2000)
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).remove();
});;
```

If I do

```
$('#cursor').clone().appendTo(".trails").delay(2000)
        .queue(function() {
           $(this).fadeOut(500);
});;
```

This doesn't make anything fadeOut

Also I tried doing

```
$('#cursor').clone().fadeOut(500).appendTo(".trails").delay(2000)
        .queue(function() {
            $(this).remove();
});;
```

But this make all clone fadeOut because of the reference

Any solution to this ?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: `$('#cursor').clone().fadeOut(500)` will only fadeOut the clone just created.  Unless you changed something inside the .queue that's different in your code and what's pasted here.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with your options: https://jsfiddle.net/654khLgw/.    It's odd that `.remove()` and `.hide()` work but `.fadeOut()` does not work.  I've added some hide/fadeout buttons to affect all copies (just for testing) after the event, which should work fine, but doesn't.

Comment: You could add a css class with opacity transition: https://jsfiddle.net/654khLgw/1/  (3rd button and add a .remove)  but that doesn't explain why `.fadeOut` doesn't work